# Getting JCO_ERROR_SYSTEM_FAILURE with SAP JCo call

Tags: java, jco

I am getting below error while invoking customized function through JCo. Please see the image for input parameters and types.

> com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (104) JCO_ERROR_SYSTEM_FAILURE: Exception condition "CNTL_ERROR" triggered

Below is the code snippet to assign values to input parameters to function and passing date and time values as string in format **yyyyMMdd**  and **HHmmss**:

```
JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("ZMARC_AUT10");
JCoParameterList params = function.getImportParameterList();
{
params.setValue("I_DATEFROM",fromDate);
params.setValue("I_TIMEFROM",fromTime);
params.setValue("I_DATETO",toDate);
params.setValue("I_TIMETO",toTime);
params.setValue("I_USER", username);
}
```

Here is the error trace:

> ```
> Caused by: com.sap.conn.rfc.exceptions.RfcGetException: Exception condition 
>    "CNTL_ERROR" triggered
>   at com.sap.conn.rfc.engine.RfcImp.ab_rfcerror(RfcImp.java:1176)
>   at com.sap.conn.rfc.engine.RfcGet.ab_rfcget(RfcGet.java:120)
>   at com.sap.conn.rfc.engine.RfcRcv.ab_rfcreceive(RfcRcv.java:33)
>   at com.sap.conn.rfc.engine.RfcIoOpenCntl.RfcReceive(RfcIoOpenCntl.java:1982)
>   ... 45 more
> ```

Function import parameter list and datatypes:

[image: function import parameter list and datatypes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your called RFM ZMARC_AUT10 threw an undeclared system exception CNTL_ERROR.
You need to analyze the error in the ABAP system. Have a look into the dumps with transaction ST22 and/or debug your ABAP Remote Function Module.
In general, I furthermore recommend to avoid throwing undeclared exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure about the reason of the exception, since it is a custom rfc, but usually the CNTL_ERROR is related to the GUI objects call (ALV for example)

I believe you are trying to instantiate one of these objects, but via RFC you don't have a GUI available.

Please check the RFC code looking for a custom container or alv or similar